# iTunes on OS X: How to rename files using in-line editing in main window, using keyboard only?

Tags: itunes, keyboard, macos

When I'm on my Windows computer and using iTunes, I can conveniently hit the **F2** key when I have a song selected, rename the song using the in-line edit field that appears, and then hit **Enter** to commit the change.  No mouse or *Get Info* dialog is used in the process.

**Is there a keyboard-only method in iTunes on OS X for quickly renaming a song?**

On OS X, I can avoid iTunes' *Get Info* dialog by using the mouse to click twice ... not *double* clicking, but rather: click, wait, click again .. (and getting the timing right is annoying!)  Such clicking activates in-line editing functionality (so I know it exists) but it requires the mouse. How can I activate the in-line editing functionality with just the keyboard?

I tried **F2** on OS X and that didn't work.  I also tried **Enter**, which can be used to in-line edit file names in Finder, but that didn't work either :-/

I'm interested in renaming files with the keyboard only because I have a ton of songs imported with *"Artist Name - Song Name"* titles to correct.

Comment: As an alternative to renaming the tracks manually, there are various scripts on the Doug's Applescripts for iTunes site that could help automate it - http://dougscripts.com/itunes/index.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There sure is.

When you have a song selected, you can press <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>return</kbd> and it will allow you to quickly edit the song title.

Comment: **Thank you!**  Works.  I'll mark this as accepted as soon as I can (there's a minimum 10 minute wait :-)  Would you happen to know if there is a list of iTunes keyboard shortcuts anywhere?

Comment: Yes, sir. [It's on Apple's website](http://www.apple.com/itunes/how-to/shortcuts.html). I'm not sure if that one is on there or not. I just happened to know about it already.

Comment: Thanks; that list looks familiar.  Yes, oddly, the shortcut in your answer for renaming a file is *not* on that list, or I'd have learned about it sooner.  :-)  Would be nice if Apple accepted feedback on such pages.

Comment: You can always provide Apple with feedback on their [feedback site](http://www.apple.com/feedback/). Not sure if it does anything, but at least you'll be heard by somebody :)

Comment: Enter (⌤ or fn-return) should also be equivalent to ⌘↩.

Comment: Cool.  (that is the Enter key by the number pad).